# Text is placed directly behind a text

Tags: c, function, file

I want to write a program that collects data and stores it. But when I try to use the function that I wrote, the text is displayed directly behind the text and I can't make an input on the first question.

```c
void new_entry(void)
{
    struct mensch
    {
        char name[30];
        char adress[30];
        int telefon;
        char geschlecht[30];
        char email[30];
    } data;

    FILE* file;
    char temp[30];

    printf("Please enter the name: ");
    fgets(data.name, sizeof data.name, stdin);

    printf("Please enter the adress: ");
    fgets(data.adress, sizeof data.adress, stdin);

    printf("Please enter the Telefon-number: ");
    fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin);
    data.telefon = atoi(temp);

    printf("Please enter the gender: ");
    fgets(data.geschlecht, sizeof data.geschlecht, stdin);

    printf("Please enter the email: ");
    fgets(data.email, sizeof data.email, stdin);


    file = fopen(FILE_PATH, "a+");

    fwrite(&data, 1, sizeof data, file);

    fclose(file);
}
```

The output is:

```
Please enter the name: Please enter the adress:
```

That's why I can't input anything on the first question.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally an all-English one.

Comment: Simplify things. First get your input reading tested, e.g. by echoing it to verify what you get. Do the file thing later, it looks fishy by itself.

Comment: This only means, there was unread data in input-buffer from previous prompts. Share complete code for clarity.

Comment: @SparKot Do not ask for "complete code". It confuses askers and you get into a discussion of "long", "private", "classified". So please ask instead for a [mre] (type `[mre]` for convenience).

Comment: Consider using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler to try your code in an alternative environment. I suspect you have unusual input/output settings at home.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that a newline character was in the input buffer i cleared it with that:

```
while(getc(stdin) != '\n');
```